# Angular 5 How to read - list array data from firestore documents

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore

In collection companies there's a documents with model

```
company: example
address: nowhere
users:{
  123456789:{
   email: qwerty@example.com
  }
}
```

where 123456789 is user's id

To get data from documents

```
this.compColl = this.afs.collection('companies');
this.comp = this.compColl.valueChanges();
```

To list data in view

```
<li *ngFor="let cmp of comp | async">{{cmp.company}}</li>
```

This working for fields company and address but not working for

```
<li *ngFor="let cmp of comp | async">{{cmp.email}}</li>
```

How to list users email from this document

Comment: To acces `email`, you need to access two other objects which are `users` and `123456789` which is probably the user ID.

Comment: I thought so, but I don't know how to access user Id when there is no chance to know what is user id and there could be more users in one document. Should I remodel document to access users IDs

Comment: Try this`<li *ngFor="let user of comp.users | async">{{user.email}}</li>`

Comment: No, that's not working

Comment: Where is any ARRAY....??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
users:{
  123456789:{
   email: qwerty@example.com
  }
}
```

If you want to get `qwerty@example.com` you can use

```
<li *ngFor="let cmp of comp | async">{{cmp.users[123456789].email}}</li>
```

users is an object and not an array so you can't use `<li *ngFor="let user of comp.users | async">{{user.email}}</li>`. If you want to use it, your database should return something like this:

```
company: example
address: nowhere
users:[ //instead of {
  123:{
   email: qwerty@example.com
  },
  456:{
   email: qwerty@example.com
  },
] //instead of }
```